# Is there such thing as too many commits in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-connector

We use MySQL Connector C++, have a connection pool class, and also use stored procedures.

Are there any issues with committing in both the C++ Connection Pool layer, and within the stored procedures?

This is not a question about can the commits cause issues because one is misplaced, but rather-

**Can there be too many commits?**

Would there be anything wrong with issuing a commit 1000 times after every MySQL Query/Statement?

Comment: It makes transactions pointless if you do.

Comment: Assume we are putting the commits exactly where we want them...i.e. Our transactions are exactly like we need them. The only question I have is, is it a problem to issue multiple commits, when simply only one commit is necessary?

Comment: No, commits dont nest. You can use as many commits as you want (and start transactions too), if none is open, it will not do anything. You have either a transaction open or not.

Comment: You can have "too many" commits if the one in your stored procedure commits something that should be rolled back later.